# CodeIgniter ActiveRecord adding a random id field

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

```
  $updatedOrder = array(
    'ship_status'      =>  'shipped',
    'shipped_carrier'  =>  (string)$selectedShipper->shipper->name,
    'base_rate'        =>  (float)$selectedShipper->rate,
    'discount_rate'    =>  (float)$selectedShipper->rate,
    'tracking_number'  => '123',

  );

  $this->orders_m->where('id', $tmpOrder->id)
    ->update('orders', $updatedOrder);
```

This yields the following SQL query: UPDATE `default_orders` SET `ship_status` = 'shipped', `shipped_carrier` = 'UPS Next Day Air', `base_rate` = 22.85, `discount_rate` = 22.85, `tracking_number` = '123' WHERE `id` = '1' AND `id` = 'orders'

Where did that last bit come from? `id='orders'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure that `$tmpOrder->id` is a variable and not an array.

```
var_dump($tmpOrder->id);
```

Maybe there is an error somewhere where you are getting the `$tmpOrder` and it returns an array for that.